# Creating a large click-to-deploy cassandra cluster

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have worked through a number of quota issues in trying to stand up a 30 node click-to-deploy cassandra cluster. The next issue is that the data disks are not becoming available within the 300 seconds allotted in *wait-for-disk.sh*.

I've tried several times in us-central1-b, once in us-central1-a and the results range from half of the disks up to 24 of 30. The disks eventually all show up, so no quota issue here, just the timing as far as I can tell.

I've been able to ssh into one node and nearly figure out which steps to run, setting up required env vars and running the steps in /gagent/. I've gotten the disk mounted and configured and get cassandra started but the manually repaired node is still missing from the all-important CASSANDRA_NODE_VIEW_NAME and I must be missing some services because I still can't run *cqlsh* on the manually repaired node.

It's a bit tedious to set up this way but I could complete the cluster this way manually. Do I need to get it added to the view? How? Or is there a way to specify a longer timeout in *wait-for-disk.sh*? I'd be willing to wait a pretty long time over doing the remaining setup manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We'll look at updating the disk wait value for the next release. Thanks for the feedback!  You should be able to join the Cassandra cluster manually after running the install scripts in /gagent. Let me know if you're still having trouble.

Comment: I got it to work in us-central1-c during off hours. Might be a coincidence, the last three disks came in just under the 300 second limit.